# Will the Taproot upgrade solve Bitcoin's scalability issues?

Tags: lightning-network, scalability, taproot

I understand that scaling Bitcoin is a complicated process so a single upgrade probably won't solve the whole problem, but what do you think the impact of the Taproot upgrade will be on Bitcoin's scalability? Will the lightning network solve some scalability issues and gain real world adoption?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Taproot can boost bitcoin to how many transaction per second?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/106787/taproot-can-boost-bitcoin-to-how-many-transaction-per-second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taproot increases slightly the throughput of transactions in the Bitcoin base layer. This increase can certainly not be considered a solution to scalability. However, its implications for the lightning network are severe. For example with taproot one can create cancelable payments to mitigate a stuck onion. This results in an improved user experience and, in combination with other techniques like redundancy in multi-path payments, an improved payment reliability which might help with adoption. However, such points are hard to measure and quantify.